# Storing ASP.NET Web Component Properties in Style Sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, styles

Is it possible to store properties of an ASP.NET web control in a CSS file?
Specifially, I'd like to do this for a `GridView`.

For example: Rather than specifying:

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGrid" runat="server" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Can I put those colors in a CSS file, and then specify the `CssClass` for the entire GridView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hi  you can define the CSS class like this

```
.AltRowStyle
{
    background-color: White;
    color: #284775;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRowStyle"/>
```

Similarly for the rest,

Comment: Hi, thanks. Do you know of a way to store them all in a single CSS class such that each `Style` (AlternatingRowStyle, EditRowStyle, FooterStyle) will not have to be called out individually?

Comment: @Eric you can't do it directly -- you'd have to inspect the actual HTML rendered by the control, and apply styles to those elements (table, tr, td). Even then you may not be able to identify/select all the matching elements exactly, since they may not be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the GridView to a theme, that way you don't have to style every GridView on your website.
On your theme.skin add the grid code with the css classes then on your aspx pages don't add any style.